# Flask listens only on 127.0.0.1 ignoring host parameter

Tags: python, flask, lan, netcat

I'm using Flask on Windows 7. Flask and related versions are below:

```
Flask==0.10.1
Werkzeug==0.9.3
```

Accessing the app from the same computer is OK using `http://127.0.0.1:5000`
However from another computer in LAN the access fails: `http://192.168.101.103:5000`

I start the app with these parameters:

```
#app.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run( host='0.0.0.0:5000')
```

One thing I don't understand is, when I start netcat on the same computer, where Flask is currently listening on the same port, it works, and netcat is even accessible from another computer:

```
>c:\Python27\python manage.py runserver
>
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
```

works ...

```
>nc -l -p 5000
```

works on the same computer, same port ???

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: de-DE
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0;

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: 192.168.101.103:5000
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

even accepting connection from another computer ???

So beside the obvious question, how to get Flask serving for LAN, I'm curious, how could two processes of one machine listen on the same port?

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [port](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.run) goes in it's own parameter:

```
app.run(
    host="0.0.0.0",
    port=5000
)
```

Comment: Looks like the statement was ignored. I disabled `if __name__ == '__main__':` and got the error on `app.run( host="0.0.0.0:5000")` Now it works, but have strange start/stop behavior. Sometimes on restart it Flask though binds to 127.0.0.1. I think I have to go for nginx as the proxy server for the Flask for serving in LAN

Comment: Don't use the built-in server for anything but development work. It's not built for it. In production, use gunicorn or another container.